# Reformat a datetime column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe df containing datetimes and their respective values. Now I want to make some format changes to each datetime in the dataframe, but noticed that a normal for loop doesn't actually change anything in the dataframe.

This is what I tried, and also shows what I'm trying to do:

```
#original format of the datetimes: sunnuntai 1.1.2017 00:00

for i in df["Datetime"]:

#removes the string containing the weekday from the beginning
    i = re.sub("^[^ ]* ","", i) 

#converts 1.1.2017 00:00 into 2017-01-01 00:00
    i = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

How should I go about doing these format changes permanently? Thank you.

Comment: Is `sunnuntai` a part of the data as well?

Comment: Yes, but I want to remove it (it's the weekday) and only leave the date and time like 2017-01-01 00:00. The original i is "sunnuntai 1.1.2017 00:00", "sunnuntai 1.1.2017 01:00" and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ditch the loop, aim to vectorize. I break down the steps —

1. use `str.split` to get rid of leading text,
2. `pd.to_datetime` with `dayfirst=True` for datetime conversion, and
3. `dt.strftime` to convert the result to your format

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['Datetime'].str.split(n=1).str[1], dayfirst=True
).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! It seems working with Pandas is quite different than working with "normal" python lists and dictionaries, I thought for loop would be a good way to do this.